# foreach use with classes php

Tags: php, arrays, class, foreach

So I basically have a multiple upload input that allows users to upload any number of images at one time, I then need to save a copy and resize a thumbnail and save that as well.

I have been using the class available here for resizing and uploading my images with php, http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

however I am having issues when I use foreach with it, the SimpleImage() doesnt work, do I need to specify this before the foreach or something of that nature.

Here is my code,

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['ref']['name']) as $i) { 
  $time = date("fYhis");
  $destination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs";
  $tdestination="./../img/treatments/" .$pageid. "/refimgs/thumbs";
     include('image.php');
  $image = new SimpleImage();
  $image->load($_FILES['ref']['name'][$i]);
  $image->save($destination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');      
  $image->resizeToWidth(140);   
  $image->save($t_destination . '/' .$time . $i . '.jpg');    
 }
```

Comment: why you place include(image.php'); and $image = new SimpleImage()  inside loop ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If image.php contains the definition of `SimpleImage` then you can't include it over and over!

Comment: Right, you are correct, moved those and it fixed it

Answer (score 1):

before all the code, you must test if the image is uploaded

```
bool is_uploaded_file ( string $filename )
```

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Right, theres some security things that I know I need to still do, but as it stands the actual function doesnt work